# AWS S3 expire objects based on rules

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backup

I have a database being backed up to AWS S3 every 15 minutes, however it is replicating a lot of data that is not needed.

I'd like to be able to set a rule on AWS that after 60 days, it would keep just one file for each day (the latest) and delete the other 95 files.

I can't rely on file names as they are prone to change.

Is this achievable with AWS? I've been searching but haven't found anything remotely similar.

Comment: I don't think you can do this purely with rules.  Likely you'll need to create something like a Lambda that runs once a day to tag all but one object to remove for each day, and then a rule that removes tagged objects, and another to remove objects older than 60 days.

Comment: What are you using to create the backup? Often, backup utilities have the ability to specify such options, and many of them know how to store data on S3.

Answer (score -2):

You can use S3's bucket to set life cycle rules. Bucket life cycle rules can be used to configure multiple schemes. Here I only use the Tag (key-value) scheme as a demonstration.
Here is my Golang demo:

```
// This file is part of <workname>.
// Copyright 2023 (c) Shutian.Ka <kst157521@163.com>.
// license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

package fdsvideo

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3/types"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    log_sdk "hawk.reli/pkg/log.sdk"
    "strconv"
)

type FdsVideoService struct {
    FdsID        string
    FdsExpireDay int
    S3Client     *s3.Client
}
type FdsVideoOption func(*FdsVideoService)

func FdsVdoExpDayOpt(day int) FdsVideoOption {
    return func(fds *FdsVideoService) {
        fds.FdsExpireDay = day
    }
}
func FdsVdoIDOpt(id string) FdsVideoOption {
    return func(fds *FdsVideoService) {
        fds.FdsID = id
    }
}
func WithS3ClientOpt(client *s3.Client) FdsVideoOption {
    return func(s *FdsVideoService) {
        s.S3Client = client
    }
}

func NewFdsService(opts ...FdsVideoOption) *FdsVideoService {
    svc := &FdsVideoService{}

    for i := 0; i < len(opts); i++ {
        opts[i](svc)
    }

    return svc
}

// SetFdsS3Expired 视频 S3 存储设置过期
//
//  S3 声明周期规则 与 S3 文件对象, 绑定纽带或媒介是使用标签(key-value)联系起来的.
//
// Args:
//   - bucket: string, S3 存储桶
//   - key: string, S3 文件对象
func (s *FdsVideoService) SetFdsS3Expired(bucket, key string) error {
    // init args.
    validityName := "validity"
    validityDays := strconv.FormatInt(int64(s.FdsExpireDay), 10)
    validityID := fmt.Sprintf("%d-%s", s.FdsExpireDay, validityName)
    hasValidity := false

    // log_sdk.Errorf 我自己定义的 Error, 此处替换为你自己的 Error.

    // 查询对应标签有效期规则是否存在
    payload := &s3.GetBucketLifecycleConfigurationInput{Bucket: aws.String(bucket)}
    configuration, err := s.S3Client.GetBucketLifecycleConfiguration(context.Background(), payload)
    if err != nil {
        return log_sdk.Errorf("aws-s3-getbucketlifecycle-err: %s", err.Error())
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(configuration.Rules); i++ {
        // 优先使用ID查找
        if *configuration.Rules[i].ID == validityID {
            hasValidity = true
            break
        }

        byt, _ := json.Marshal(configuration.Rules[i].Filter)
        filter := types.LifecycleRuleFilterMemberTag{}
        _ = json.Unmarshal(byt, &filter)

        // 使用标签与过期天数查找
        expirationDays := configuration.Rules[i].Expiration.Days
        if *filter.Value.Key == validityName && *filter.Value.Value == validityDays && expirationDays == int32(s.FdsExpireDay) {
            hasValidity = true
            break
        }
    }

    // 未查找到对应规则, 新增对应标签有效期规则
    if hasValidity == false {
        lifecycleConfig := &types.BucketLifecycleConfiguration{Rules: make([]types.LifecycleRule, 0)}
        lifecycleConfig.Rules = append(lifecycleConfig.Rules, configuration.Rules...)
        lifecycleConfig.Rules = append(lifecycleConfig.Rules, types.LifecycleRule{
            Status:     types.ExpirationStatusEnabled,
            Expiration: &types.LifecycleExpiration{Days: int32(s.FdsExpireDay)},
            Filter:     &types.LifecycleRuleFilterMemberTag{Value: types.Tag{Key: aws.String(validityName), Value: aws.String(validityDays)}},
            ID:         aws.String(validityID),
        })
        payload := &s3.PutBucketLifecycleConfigurationInput{Bucket: aws.String(bucket), LifecycleConfiguration: lifecycleConfig}
        _, err := s.S3Client.PutBucketLifecycleConfiguration(context.Background(), payload)
        if err != nil {
            return log_sdk.Errorf("aws-s3-putbucketlifecycle-err: %s", err.Error())
        }
    }

    // 给object设置标签
    tagging := &types.Tagging{TagSet: make([]types.Tag, 0)}
    tagging.TagSet = append(tagging.TagSet, types.Tag{Key: aws.String(validityName), Value: aws.String(validityDays)})
    _, err = s.S3Client.PutObjectTagging(context.Background(), &s3.PutObjectTaggingInput{
        Bucket:  aws.String(bucket),
        Key:     aws.String(key),
        Tagging: tagging,
    })
    if err != nil {
        return log_sdk.Errorf("aws-s3-putobjecttagging-err: %s", err.Error())
    }

    return nil
}
```

> 1. First imagine your tag key and tag value, for example: `key_i:val_1`.
> 2. Find the `Bucket` life cycle rule and see if there is corresponding tag data.
> 3. Step `2` was not found, create a `Bucket` life cycle rule, and set the corresponding tag (key-value) trigger scheme.
> 4. Edit the file `Object` and set a label (key-value) for it. The label here is consistent with the life cycle.

At this point, your file can see the life cycle time.